# windows 10: some icons show default picture at the quick launch bar

Tags: windows-10, icons, quicklaunch

Quite a while ago I created a "separator" icon to get a more neat quick launch bar. I do not remember anymore how I finally created the .ico file.

Unfortunately only the default picture is shown (magnified view)
[image: my quick launch bar with broken icon picture]:

The icon looks like this: [image: icon as it should look like] when the .ico file is opened for example in Photo.

Question: where can I find the right setting so that the icon will be displayed correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The quick launch bar shows icons for the items in your Quick Launch folder ([user folder]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch). If you open the Properties dialog for those "shortcut" files, on the Shortcut tab, towards the bottom will be a button labeled "Change Icon ...". Pressing it will show the icon and where it is located. A "Browse" button will let you explore various folders that contain icons, so find where the icon file you wish to show is, and choose it.

Answer (score 0):

@kreemoweet: I had put several .ico files in the quick launch folder. You can see the result in the clipped screenshot of my initial posting.
If I click on the properties in the quick launch bar of those .ico files no option is shown for change icon.

Based on your answer I put the .ico file in another folder and added actual shortcuts in the quick launch folder. Then I changed the icon for each of the (relevant) shortcuts.

And that seems to work out (I am curious what will happen after the next restart, tough). Thanks for your swift reaction to my posting!

The result now looks like this: [image: QuickLaunchRepaired]

Brief update on December 2022: This approach works like a charm even more than a year and many reboots later. Problem solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).